# PHP: Guzzle fails when sending large files

Tags: php, guzzle, php-curl

Using Guzzle for uploading files to a REST API:

My PHP Code is:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;

$apiClient = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $url,
    'timeout'  => 5, // seconds
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

$postParams = [
    RequestOptions::MULTIPART => [
        ...$multipartParams,
        [                        
            'name' => 'upload',
            'contents' => Psr7\Utils::streamFor(fopen($filePath, 'r')),
            'filename' => $postFields['filename'],
        ]
    ]
];

$response = $apiClient->post("upload", $postParams);
```

This code results in errors for files above 10MB:

```
Error: #0 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#4 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#5 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#6 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#7 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#8 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(63): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#9 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#10 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(331): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#11 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(168): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#12 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('POST', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri), Array)
#13 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/ClientTrait.php(95): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('POST', 'upload', Array)
#14 /app/CkanApiClient.php(140): GuzzleHttp\Client->post('upload', Array)
#15 /app/ckan-upload.php(142): CkanApiClient->send('upload', Array)
#16 {main}
```

When performing file uploads with `curl` on the command line the uploads work.

How to make my code work? How to debug what's the error?

My environment:

- Composer: guzzlehttp/guzzle  7.5.0
- Dockerfile: `php:8.2-cli`
- PHP: `memory_limit = 2048M`

Comment: You missed one line of ERROR! the first line or last is the description of the error. you uploaded just stack trace. provide error to solve

Comment: What is error? Maybe your server does not allow, not Guzzle itself? From your stack trace I see it's handling response, not just throwing error

Comment: the guzzle doc : multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to use one or the other. Use form_params for application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for multipart/form-data requests.

This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json

Comment: @Alijvhr after adding the error in the `catch()` it was clear: it was a timeout. Setting timeout to 30 seconds was the solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was the timeout of 5 seconds. Large files take longer to upload.

Setting the timeout to 30 seconds was the solution:

```
$apiClient = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $url,
    'timeout'  => 30, // seconds
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you php configurations are blocking upload. `guzzlehttp` doesn't have one.

**Note: `curl` command in cli doesn't have limitations**

You need to increase the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Then restart your `php-fpm` or any program that runs your php.

You can't change these valuesat runtime; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed.

[Read more about php.ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Maybe also a timeout issue?

Comment: if the file size is limited timeout will happen too. but he is sure at a certain size and above this will happen!